# Does returning a constructor with new parameters overwrite the instance object?

Tags: python, oop, object, return

I am trying to model a drunk person walking. I want him to move. When I call move, I will tell him to move to a new location signified by X and Y coordinates by returning a new Location.

I'm having trouble visualizing what's going on. Presumably I need to initialize a Location object like a = Location(1,2). Do I call move on the object? So a.move(2,2)? And that method returns a new Location object with x and y values as 1+2,2+2 or 3,4? Am I overwriting something here?

```
class Location(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        """x and y are floats"""
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def move(self, deltaX, deltaY):
        """deltaX and deltaY are floats"""
        return Location(self.x+deltaX, self.y+deltaY)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Presumably I need to initialize a Location object like `a = Location(1,2)`.

Yes.

> Do I call move on the object? So `a.move(2,2)`?

Yes.

> And that method returns a new Location object with x and y values as 1+2,2+2 or 3,4?

Yes, with the way you've written the method.

> Am I overwriting something here?

No, not with the way you've written the method.

Your method does not really "move" the Location object; it creates a new, different Location object with different `x` and `y`.  This may or may not be what you want; that depends on what you want to do.

If you wanted to update the existing object, you would write your method something like this:

```
def move(self, deltaX, deltaY):
    """deltaX and deltaY are floats"""
    self.x += deltaX
    self.y += deltaY
```

This would indeed "overwrite" the object's existing `x` and `y` with the new values.

Comment: Thanks! I am used to thinking in terms of increments in Java. The whole init syntax and calling something that's not a constructer per se (in the Java sense) gets me jumbled.